# Vigenére Cipher with Numbers in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, vigenere

How can i also encrypt/decrypt numbers using the Vigenére cipher?

**Code:**

```
 $str = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s";
$key = "RANDOM KEY";

printf("Text: %s\n", $str);
printf("key:  %s\n", $key);

$cod = encipher($str, $key, true); printf("Code: %s\n", $cod);
$dec = encipher($cod, $key, false); printf("Back: %s\n", $dec);

function encipher($src, $key, $encoder)
{
    $key = strtoupper($key);
    $src = strtoupper($src);
    $dest = '';

    /* strips non-letters */
    for($i = 0; $i <= strlen($src); $i++) {
        $char = substr($src, $i, 1);
        if(ctype_upper($char)) {
            $dest .= $char;
        }
    }

    for($i = 0; $i <= strlen($dest); $i++) {
        $char = substr($dest, $i, 1);
        if(!ctype_upper($char)) {
            continue;
        }
        $dest = substr_replace($dest,
            chr (
                ord('A') +
                ($encoder
                   ? ord($char) - ord('A') + ord($key[$i % strlen($key)]) - ord('A')
                   : ord($char) - ord($key[$i % strlen($key)]) + 26
                ) % 26
            )
        , $i, 1);
    }

    return $dest;
}
```

Can i just get a way to keep the numbers after i strip the non alphabetic characters, and it will work just fine? (Maybe using regex as a easier way)

Comment: This might be more appropriate for http://crypto.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Vigenère uses a square grid to encrypt and decrypt.  With letters, it uses a [26 x 26 grid](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9a/Vigen%C3%A8re_square_shading.svg/900px-Vigen%C3%A8re_square_shading.svg.png).  With both letters and digits it uses a 36 x 36 grid.  With bytes it uses a 256 x 256 grid.  For digits only, use a 10 x 10 grid and a key composed only of digits.